# Laravel: Update a model and a related model

Tags: php, database, laravel

I'm new to laravel and currently I'm trying to update some user information.

In my code I update the username and email for to user table and the user information in the user_info table.

It works but i feel like it can be done in much shorter code.

Also, every time I update the user_info table, a new row is inserted instead of updating the current row.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'firstName' => 'required',
            'lastName' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required',
            'cityProvince' => 'required',
            'zipPostalCode' => 'required',
        ]);

        $user = User::find($id);

        $user->name = $data['name'];
        $user->email = $data['email'];

        $user->save();

        $userInfo = new UserInfo([
            'first_name' => $data['firstName'],
            'last_name' => $data['lastName'],
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'city_province' => $data['cityProvince'],
            'zip_postalcode' => $data['zipPostalCode'],
        ]);

        $user->userInfo()->save($userInfo);

        return redirect()->route('settings.index');
    }
```

Comment: `new UserInfo` you are initiating new user info

Comment: how do you update user table. Do you use same function?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#updates

Comment: Map the data in an array `$userInfo = [
            'first_name' => $data['firstName'], ...
        ];` and use the update method `$user->userInfo()->update($userInfo);` you'll need that fields in the fillable array con your model

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ, If I try this the data won't be saved but there are no errors.

Comment: Add the attributes to the $fillable array in your UserInfo Model `protected $fillable = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'phone', ...];`

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has inbuilt functions, You can check [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#other-creation-methods)

You can use below code, It will check if record exist then it will update, otherwise new record inserted.

```
$uinfo = UserInfo::firstOrNew([
               'user_id' => $user->id,
         ]);
$uinfo->first_name = $data['firstName'];
$uinfo->last_name = $data['lastName'];
$uinfo->phone => $data['phone'];
$uinfo->city_province => $data['cityProvince'];
$uinfo->zip_postalcode => $data['zipPostalCode'];
$uinfo->save();
```

Comment: hmm, If I try this i get a **SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "user_id"**

Comment: Add `$uinfo->user_id = $user->id` before first_name